# How to correctly receive Pubsub JSON data?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, base64, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a GCP pipeline setup with cloud function which receives PubSub messages. The issue is everytime i publish a message(a json string) to the cloud function, the received message is somewhat different to what is expected. Below is my code:

```
import base64

def myfunc(event, context):
    #receive pusub data
    if 'data' in event:
          payload = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    else:
          payload = 'No Data'

    payloadLocal ={"considerIp":False,"wifiAccessPoints":[{
      "macAddress":"44:48:c1:a6:f3:d0",
      "signalStrength":-54,
      "signalToNoiseRatio":0,
      "channel":11,
      "age":0},{
      "macAddress":"9c:1c:12:b0:45:f1",
      "signalStrength":-43,
      "signalToNoiseRatio":0,
      "channel":11,
      "age":0},{
      "macAddress":"20:a6:cd:33:6c:f4",
      "signalStrength":-32,
      "signalToNoiseRatio":0,
      "channel":11,
      "age":0}]}
    
    #Compare the received payload from pubsub with the local payload
    #I expect to the same payload as payloadlocal
    if payloadLocal == payload:
      print("Payload same")
    else:
      print("Payload different")
```

The message that i publish using pubsub is:

```
{"considerIp":False,"wifiAccessPoints":[{
      "macAddress":"44:48:c1:a6:f3:d0",
      "signalStrength":-54,
      "signalToNoiseRatio":0,
      "channel":11,
      "age":0},{
      "macAddress":"9c:1c:12:b0:45:f1",
      "signalStrength":-43,
      "signalToNoiseRatio":0,
      "channel":11,
      "age":0},{
      "macAddress":"20:a6:cd:33:6c:f4",
      "signalStrength":-32,
      "signalToNoiseRatio":0,
      "channel":11,
      "age":0}]}
```

But when i compare payloadlocal with the payload received from the pubsub message, it is different. There is something silly that i am missing. Please could anyone point it. Thanks

Edit:
I have found the solution after numerous trials:

```
payload = base64.b64decode(event['data'])
dict_str = payload.decode("UTF-8")
payload = ast.literal_eval(dict_str)
```

I am sure there are better solutions out there but this works for me.

Comment: Explain better why literal_eval is the solution please.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the payload as a string and checking if it is equal to a dict.

Load your message this way

`payload = json.loads(base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8'))`

`json.loads` converts the string in a dict, if it is a valid dict.

Comment: Thank u for the response. But i am getting the following error now

" in raw_decode raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 15 (char 14)"

Comment: edit your question and print the content of event['data']